# How to compute the signed distance function for an implicit surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, numerical-methods, surfaces

I need to generate [a signed distance function field](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function) for an implicit surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

\begin{equation}
F(x, y, z) = 0
\end{equation}

for numerical purposes (so also an approximate method is accepted). Do I need to solve the Eikonal equation to obtain it?

For example, let's take an ellipsoid:

\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2} - 1 = 0
\end{equation}

Can I compute the SDF analitically?

Comment: What is a signed distance field?

Comment: @TedShifrin You are right, sorry. I fixed. What I'm looking for is the signed distance function (in theory as a field: i.e. Having a value for each point of the embedding volume).